# Generate and handle software interupt

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, arm, embedded

could somebody show me how to generate software interrupt under Linux and then handle it with request_irq?

or maybe this is not possible.

Comment: Why do you ask? On the application side, why can't you use signals?

Comment: signals are t h e software interrupts in linux userspace.

Comment: Eventually I want to pass interrupts from host system to guest system in qemu. This is for testing and educational purpose.

Comment: What architecture? On x86 you generate a software interrupt with the `int` instruction. `int 0x80` is how you make old-style system calls, for example.

Comment: In generalized manner interrupt handlers are part of the kernel. Jumping to your own code is just a function call. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @codegeek It is for my virtualization system with qemu. I want to be able to send interupts from host to guest. I need software interupts to test it and I'm curious how to do this.

Comment: OK. ARM interrupt vector table can be modified for software interrupts,may you can find this helpful. [here](http://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/blog/2011/01/16/writing-interrupt-routines-using-gcc-for-arm/) and [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/arm926-interrupts-in-qemu/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use softirq instead.
You can define your sofirq via editing include/linux/interrupt.h.
and then use function rasie_softirq() instead of reuqest_irq(),which
notify the kernel there is softirq needs to be processed. then kernel will
execute it at a appropriate in software interrupt context.

Example API

```
1. open_softwareirq();
2. raise_softirq();
```